# UITabBar and safeAreaLayoutGuide

Tags: tabbar, safearealayoutguide

I have a viewcontroller that I added a UITabBar, its bottom being constrained to the top of the bottom layout guide.
If I constraint it to the bottom of the superview, on new devices, tabs get hidden

[image]

The issue I have is the bottom layout guide dosnt match the tab bar colour (obviously), question is how to I fix?[image]

The only solution I can think of adding a uiview in the safe area, with its colour matching the UITabBar but that feels over complicated.